# Symfony create routing for mydomain.com/parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I need to create a routing rule in Symfony to receive a parameter as the first value after the domain.

I mean, www.mydomain.com/myusername

Username is a variable to show the profile of an user.

Is it possible that in some cases, Symfony identify it needs to consider this as a variable (dynamically) and in other cases it needs to follow the normal case with /controller/action?

Comment: What version of Symfony are we talking about here ? 1.4 ? 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what version you're referring to but it's possible to have such conflicting routing in Symfony 2. What you should do is add your route at the very bottom of `app/config/routing.yml`. The order is important, because in Symfony the first matched route always wins as stated in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements)

> The Symfony router will always choose the first matching route it finds.

So, by having all of your other routes come **before** the matching route for `domain.com/*` everything else should be working.

I must say, though, this isn't considered a best practice because it's usually harder to maintain and debug. Furthermore, if you have a lot of routes it would take considerably longer time for your requests to complete, because it would go though **all** routes until it matches the last route.

Answer (score 0):

Add your parameter as an optional one like:

```
public functionName($parameter = null)
{
    if($parameter = null)
    { //render regular view }
    else
    { //render user profile view}
}
```

Hope i got your question right
Cheers

Comment: This solution is quite impractical. What if you have multiple controllers with multiple methods and business logic? You'll need to be doing HVMC which would make your life a lot harder.

Comment: @tftd true, but the question was targetting only the landing page i guess, which is why i suggested this workaround